# Expand second argument/counter

Tags: macros, counters

I'm currently working on a somewhat automatic way to generate B+ trees.

Thus I introduced a new macro to generate the content of a matrix of nodes which should also generate the labels automatically. This macro calls another macro to do this. I've added one `\expandafter` before to expand `\x`.

But I'm unable to get it to work correctly with the counter `\ga`.
The value of the counter seems to be 4 in every case. So referencing to `l1-n1-p4` works fine, but all other references (i.e. `l1-n1-p2`) cause an error.

Here's my code I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, fit, calc}

\begin{document}

\newcount\ga
\ga = 1%

\newcommand{\drawkeymatrixnode}[4] {
    |(l#4-n#3-p#2) [fill=gray!50]| \vphantom{1} \&
    \ifx&#1&
        % empty argument #1
        |(l#4-n#3-k#2) [text width = 0.5cm, align = center]| \vphantom{1} \&
    \else
        % #1 not empty
        |(l#4-n#3-k#2) [text width = 0.5cm, align = center]| #1 \&
    \fi
}

\newcommand{\drawpointermatrixnode}[3] {
    |(l#3-n#2-p#1) [fill=gray!50]| \vphantom{1} \&
}

\newcommand{\btreematrixnode}[3]{%
    % #1 ... the level of the node
    % #2 ... number of node of level #1
    % #3 ... values as comma separated list

    \ga = 1%
    \let\mymatrixnodecontent\empty
    \foreach \x in #3 {%
        \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\mymatrixnodecontent\expandafter{\expandafter\drawkeymatrixnode\expandafter{\x}{\the\ga}{#2}{#1}}%
        \global\advance\ga by1
    }
    \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\mymatrixnodecontent\expandafter{\expandafter\drawpointermatrixnode\expandafter{\the\ga}{#2}{#1}}%
    \gappto\mymatrixnodecontent{\\}%
}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale = 1.0,
        ->,
        >=stealth',
        level 1/.style = {
            sibling distance = 7cm,
            level distance = 1.5cm
        },
        level 2/.style = {
            sibling distance = 3.5cm,
            level distance = 1.5cm
        },
        edge from parent/.style = {}, % no connecting arrows
        bnode/.style = {
            matrix,
            matrix of nodes,
            ampersand replacement=\&,
            nodes = {draw, rectangle, minimum height = 0.5cm}
        }
    ] 

    \btreematrixnode{1}{1}{{1, 2, 3}}
    \let\cLOne\mymatrixnodecontent
    \btreematrixnode{2}{1}{{4, 5, 6}}
    \let\cLTwoNOne\mymatrixnodecontent
    \btreematrixnode{2}{2}{{7, 8, 9}}
    \let\cLTwoNTwo\mymatrixnodecontent

    \node[bnode] (root) {\cLOne}
    child {
        node[bnode] {\cLTwoNOne}
    }
    child {
        node[bnode] {\cLTwoNTwo}
    };

    % should be \draw (l1-n1-p2) -- (l2-n1-k2);
    \draw (l1-n1-p4) -- (l2-n1-k4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

So I'd like to generate labels of the form `l<levelnr>-n<nodenr>-k<keynr>` and `l<levelnr>-n<nodenr>-p<pointernr>` respectively. So for a node containing 3 keys and 4 pointers in node 1 of the first level, I'd like to get the `l1-n1-p1`, `l1-n1-k1`, `l1-n1-p2`, `l1-n1-k2`, `l1-n1-p3`, `l1-n1-k3`, `l1-n1-p4`. But it seems that I only `l1-n1-p4` get generated because I get a `no shape named l1-n1-p2 is known` error.

I've already read some threads I found searching for 'expandafter multiple arguments' but I've not figured out by now how to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to expand the `\the\ga` argument. For example:

```
...
\newcommand{\btreematrixnode}[3]{%
    % #1 ... the level of the node
    % #2 ... number of node of level #1
    % #3 ... values as comma separated list
    \ga = 1%
    \let\mymatrixnodecontent\empty
    \foreach \x in #3 {%
        \edef\tmp{{\x}{\the\ga}}%
        \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\mymatrixnodecontent\expandafter
            {\expandafter\drawkeymatrixnode\tmp{#2}{#1}}%
        \global\advance\ga by1
    }
    \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\mymatrixnodecontent\expandafter
        {\expandafter\drawpointermatrixnode\expandafter{\the\ga}{#2}{#1}}%
    \gappto\mymatrixnodecontent{\\}%
}
...
    % should be \draw (l1-n1-p2) -- (l2-n1-k2);
    %    \draw (l1-n1-p4) -- (l2-n1-k4);
\draw (l1-n1-p2) -- (l2-n1-k2);
...
```